# How can I make <a> align center and css

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag that I want to use with bootstrap. How can I make `<a>` always align in the center when responsive?. I must use `margin-left` to do it and I also must use a `@media` query.

```
<div class="make-btn">
      <a href="/">Button</a>
</div>


.make-btn a{
  margin-left:42%; // On col-md
}
.make-btn a{
  margin-left:39%; // On col-sm
}
```

Can anyone help me with this CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use class `text-center` to align your button in center.
**Html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">

      <a class="btn btn-info" href="/">Button</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/pv4r35jc/

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your full code?

You can achieve that by putting all of that within a container for responsive width... and changing your margin to:

```
margin:0 auto
```

or you could just as easily use:

```
text-align:center;
```